# Reference alias in subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

Let's say there's a `person` table with the columns `name` and `age`.

I'm writing a DSL that generates the following SQL:

```
select *
  from (select * from person p1 inner join person p2 on p1.name = p2.name) as pj;
```

Now, I would like to be able to access `p1` and `p2` in the outer query, like this:

```
select *
  from (select * from person p1 inner join person p2 on p1.name = p2.name) as pj
  where p1.name = 'xxx'; <-- DOESN'T WORK
```

Something like `pj.p1.name` would be ideal. Is there a way to achieve this if I don't know the exact column names of `person`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `using` then just `pj.name` or even just `name`

```
create table person (id serial, name text);
insert into person (name) values ('John'),('Mary');

select *
from (
    select *
    from
        person p1
        inner join
        person p2 using(name)
) r
where name = 'John'
;
 name | id | id 
------+----+----
 John |  1 |  1
```

> A clause of the form USING ( a, b, ... ) is shorthand for ON left_table.a = right_table.a AND left_table.b = right_table.b .... Also, USING implies that only one of each pair of equivalent columns will be included in the join output, not both.

If only one side of the `join` is necessary:

```
select *
from (
    select p1.*
    from
        person p1
        inner join
        person p2 using(name)
) r
where name = 'John'
;
 id | name 
----+------
  1 | John
```

If both `join` sides are necessary then use records:

```
select (p2).id, (p1).name -- or (p2).*, (p1).*
from (
    select p1, p2
    from
        person p1
        inner join
        person p2 using(name)
) r
where (p1).name = 'John'
;
 id | name 
----+------
  1 | John
```

Comment: Unfortunately `ERROR:  column reference "name" is ambiguous`.

Comment: That's it! Didn't know about records, that solves it.

Answer (score 2):

The aliases  `p1` and `p2` are not in scope in the join condition.  you can only use the `pj` alias.  What you need to do is to be more explicit in the subquery about which columns you are selecting, rather than simply doing `SELECT * ...`:

Something like:

```
select *
  from (select p1.name, <add other required columns here> -- explicitly select one of the name columns here
          from person p1 
         inner join person p2 
            on p1.name = p2.name) as pj
  where pj.name = 'xxx' -- use pj alias here.
```

Comment: Is there a way to include all columns even if I don't know their names/count? I.e. some way to rename all columns from `p1` into `p1_*` and equivalently for `p2`?

Comment: Not that I know of. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch Extra Column give proper alias name to it

```
select *
from (select *, 
      p1.name as pjName  --Added Column and use this in where clause 
      from person p1 
      inner join person p2 on p1.name = p2.name) as pj
where pjName = 'xxx';
```

Comment: Smart, that's not a bad idea :)